# hiding or showing elements in JS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to show/hide elements using JS... it's not working, I can't get why

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="galleryInnerImageHolder"> <p> XXX </p> </div>
</body>
</html>


<script>
    document.getElementsByClassName("galleryInnerImageHolder").style.display = "block"; 
    document.getElementsByClassName("galleryInnerImageHolder").style.display = "none"; 
</script>
```

Comment: `getElement**s**ByClassName` it returns elementS not an element. The result is HtmlCollection

Answer (score -1):

getElement**s**ByClassName return array. you can do: document.getElementsByClassName("galleryInnerImageHolder")[0].style.display = "block";